# Reference request: history of analytic geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request, analytic-geometry, math-history

I am searching a book in the domain of the history of math, that describes the historical origins of analytic geometry, starting from Descartes (?), and that describes also its development (e.g. the different coordinate systems) during the centuries till today. However, the book should be for non-mathematicians (or at least for people who have a very minimal background in math). Could you please give me some references?

Thank you,
Sami

Comment: Tried in hsm.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Carl Boyer, [History of Analytic Geometry](https://books.google.it/books?id=2T4i5fXZbOYC&printsec=frontcover) (1956, also Dover reprint).